# how does this code work for detecting XP OS?

Tags: c++, windows, callstack

```c
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UINT *ptr = (UINT*) ((((UINT)&ptr) & 0x00FF0000) | 0xfe0c);
    if (*ptr) printf("higher than XP\n"); // It's really amazing!!!!
    else printf("XP\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I found this trick in the following article:

http://spareclockcycles.org/2012/02/14/stack-necromancy-defeating-debuggers-by-raising-the-dead/

But I can't figure out what common knowledge and convention behind the trick. 
Thanks for any comment.

Comment: It's officially undefined behaviour, so even when it does work, it really doesn't. If the OS version is what you're after, there are safer and less obfuscated ways, but that's probably beside the point.

Comment: The article that you linked to explains this in great detail. Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the background, but it sets up a pointer to an address calculated from the stackpointer (at 0xFE0C). Then reads the value at this address, and it is either zero (XP) or non-zero (not XP).

I doubt very much that this is a RELIABLE way to determine this. The correct way to determine the version of Windows is to use the `[GetVersion][1]`

Comment: +1 Yes - don't use it. What if it stops working correctly in W9?

Comment: Don't use ``GetVersion`` either. Use ``VerifyVersionInfo``. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303824/warning-c4996-getversionexw-was-declared-deprecated) stack overflow thread.