# warning C4996: 'GetVersionExW': was declared deprecated

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, wdk

I am working on VS 2013 in Win 8.1. 
How to solve this warning?

Comment: You could ignore the warning - the function still works. Or, you could read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451.aspx) for `GetVersionEx` and switch to the [API said documentation recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972.aspx) as a replacement.

Comment: I got the answer, as GetVersionExW is used for the earlier versions , now for Windows 8.1 and all we use anotther API. I got that from this ..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx   Thanks for the help...

Comment: i guess you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031597/error-c4996-received-when-compiling-sqlite-c-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Actually, deprecation is an error by default, at least now in 2015.  Microsoft doesn't seem to understand what "deprecated" means.

Answer (score 59):

**The basic question is "why are you calling `GetVersionExW` in the first place?" The answer to that question determines what you should do instead.**

The deprecation warning is there to give developers a heads-up about the appcompat behavior change that started in Windows 8.1. See [Windows and Windows Server compatibility cookbook: Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/w8cookbook/windows-8-and-windows-server-8-compatibility-cookbook-portal). *In short, that function doesn't return what you think it returns by default.*

Historically, badly written OS version checks are the primary source of appcompat bugs for Windows OS upgrades. There've been a number of different approaches to trying to mitigate this problem (the AppVerifier version lie, the `VerifyVersionInfo` API, etc.), and this is the most aggressive to date.

The `VersionHelpers.h` mentioned in the comments are in the Windows 8.1 SDK that comes with Visual Studio 2013. They are not a new API; they are just utility code that makes use of the `VerifyVersionInfo` API introduced back in Windows 2000. These functions are for doing "You must be this high to ride this ride" style checks which are the class of version checks that are most often badly written. The code is pretty simple. For example, the `IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater` test is:

```
VERSIONHELPERAPI
IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(WORD wMajorVersion, WORD wMinorVersion, WORD wServicePackMajor)
{
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi = {};
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
    DWORDLONG        const dwlConditionMask = VerSetConditionMask(
        VerSetConditionMask(
        VerSetConditionMask(
            0, VER_MAJORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
               VER_MINORVERSION, VER_GREATER_EQUAL),
               VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, VER_GREATER_EQUAL);

    osvi.dwMajorVersion = wMajorVersion;
    osvi.dwMinorVersion = wMinorVersion;
    osvi.wServicePackMajor = wServicePackMajor;

    return VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_MAJORVERSION | VER_MINORVERSION | VER_SERVICEPACKMAJOR, dwlConditionMask) != FALSE;
}

VERSIONHELPERAPI
IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater()
{
    return IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(HIBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), LOBYTE(_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA), 2);
}
```

You don't need to use `VersionHelpers.h` as you could just do this kind of code yourself, but they are convenient if you are already using the VS 2013 compiler. For games, I have an article [What's in a version number?](https://walbourn.github.io/whats-in-a-version-number/) which uses `VerifyVersionInfo` to do the kind of reasonable checks one should for game deployment.

> Note if you are using VS 2013 with the `v120_xp` platform toolset to target Windows XP, you'll actually be using the Windows 7.1A SDK and `#include <VersionHelpers.h>` won't work. You can of course use `VerifyVersionInfo` directly.

The other major use of `GetVersionExW` is diagnostic logs and telemetry. In this case, one option is to continue to use that API and make sure you have the right manifest entries in your application to ensure reasonably accurate results. See [Manifest Madness](https://walbourn.github.io/manifest-madness/) for details on what you do here to achieve this. The main thing to keep in mind is that unless you routinely update your code, you will eventually stop getting fully accurate information in a future version of the OS.

> Note that it is recommended you put the `<compatibility>` section in an embedded manifest whether or not you care about the results of `GetVersionEx` as general best practice. This allows the OS to automatically apply future appcompat fixes based on knowing how the app was originally tested.

For diagnostic logs, another approach that might be a bit more robust is to grab the version number out of a system DLL like `kernel32.dll` using `GetFileVersionInfoW`. This approach has a major caveat: *Do not try parsing, doing comparisons, or making code assumptions based on the file version you obtain this way; just write it out somewhere*. Otherwise you risk recreating the same bad OS version check problem that is better solved with `VerifyVersionInfo`. This option is not available to Windows Store apps, Windows phone apps, etc. but should work for Win32 desktop apps.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib" )

bool GetOSVersionString( WCHAR* version, size_t maxlen )
{
    WCHAR path[ _MAX_PATH ] = {};
    if ( !GetSystemDirectoryW( path, _MAX_PATH ) )
        return false;

    wcscat_s( path, L"\\kernel32.dll" );

    //
    // Based on example code from this article
    // http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167597
    //

    DWORD handle;
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA)
    DWORD len = GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL, path, &handle );
#else
    DWORD len = GetFileVersionInfoSizeW( path, &handle );
#endif
    if ( !len )
        return false;

    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t> buff( new (std::nothrow) uint8_t[ len ] );
    if ( !buff )
        return false;

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA)
    if ( !GetFileVersionInfoExW( FILE_VER_GET_NEUTRAL, path, 0, len, buff.get() ) )
#else
    if ( !GetFileVersionInfoW( path, 0, len, buff.get() ) )
#endif
        return false;

    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *vInfo = nullptr;
    UINT infoSize;

    if ( !VerQueryValueW( buff.get(), L"\\", reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>( &vInfo ), &infoSize ) )
        return false;

    if ( !infoSize )
        return false;

    swprintf_s( version, maxlen, L"%u.%u.%u.%u",
                HIWORD( vInfo->dwFileVersionMS ),
                LOWORD(vInfo->dwFileVersionMS),
                HIWORD(vInfo->dwFileVersionLS),
                LOWORD(vInfo->dwFileVersionLS) );
    
    return true;
}
```

If there is some other reason you are calling `GetVersionExW`, you probably shouldn't be calling it. Checking for a component that might be missing shouldn't be tied to a version check. For example, if your application requires Media Foundation, you should set a "You must be this high to ride this ride check" like the VersionHelpers.h `IsWindowsVistaOrGreater` for deployment, but at runtime you should use explicit linking via `LoadLibrary` or `LoadLibaryEx` to report an error or use a fallback if `MFPLAT.DLL` is not found.

> Explicit linking is not an option for Windows Store apps. Windows 8.x solves this
> particular problem by  having a stub `MFPLAT.DLL` and `MFStartUp` will return E_NOTIMPL.
> See ["Who moved my [Windows Media] Cheese"?](https://walbourn.github.io/who-moved-my-windows-media-cheese/)

Another example: if your application wants to use Direct3D 11.2 if it is available and otherwise uses DirectX 11.0, you'd use set a `IsWindowsVistaSP2OrGreater` minimum bar for deployment perhaps using the [D3D11InstallHelper](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/InstallHelpers/D3D11InstallHelper). Then at runtime, you'd create the DirectX 11.0 device and if it fails, you'd report an error. If you obtain a `ID3D11Device`, then you'd `QueryInterface` for a `ID3D11Device2` which if it succeeds means you are using an OS that supports DirectX 11.2. See [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

If this hypothetical Direct3D application supports Windows XP, you'd use a deployment bar of `IsWindowsXPSP2OrGreater` or `IsWindowsXPSP3OrGreater`, and then at run time use explicit linking to try to find the `D3D11.DLL`. If it wasn't present, you'd fall back to using Direct3D 9--since we set the minimum bar, we know that DirectX 9.0c or later is always present.

**They key point here is that in most cases, you should not use `GetVersionEx`.**

> Note that with **Windows 10**, `VerifyVersionInfo` and getting the file version stamp via `GetFileVersionInfo` for kernel32.lib are now subject to the same manifest based behavior as `GetVersionEx` (i.e. without the manifest GUID for Windows 10, it returns results as if the OS version were 6.2 rather than 10.0).

> For universal Windows apps on Windows 10, you can a new WinRT API [AnalyticsInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo) to get a version stamp string for diagnostic logs and telemetry.

Comment: I've been down-voted a few times here. If it's just because you hate that ``GetVersionEx`` was deprecated in the first place, your are shooting the messenger :)

Comment: The "you shouldn't even be calling" as in "you're wrong, and you should feel bad", may explain.

Comment: Tone-policing a 1000 word post over a single sentence seems odd, but I've edited that statement none-the-less. In any case, the ``GetVersion`` battle between developers and the appcompat folks has been raging for years, but the guideance in this answer is as complete as I can make it.

Comment: @manuell which says more about the person reading it than the person writing it, in my opinion. Wish people would stop being so sensitive about everything and instead focused on doing the _right_ thing, which, in this case, is to **not** use `GetVersion`

Comment: `bool GetOSVersionString( WCHAR* version, size_t maxlen )` I surprise you can write a support function like this?

Comment: Keep in mind the original answer handled Windows XP and Windows Vista, neither of which would matter these days. It's also ONLY intended for logging purposes, not making any runtime decisions.

Answer (score 10):

you can disable this warning and use GetVersionEx anyway by adding:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

Comment: The C4996 warning is telling you that ``GetVersionEx`` doesn't necessarily do what you think it does anymore. You can certainly disable the warning for Windows desktop apps, but be aware that it's going to lie to you. Hence the guidance in my answer above.

Comment: I'm trying to get some ancient code building for the express purpose of updating the version of openssl it builds with.  Of course, it is the OpenSSl code that is calling GetVersion() / GetVersionEx().   So, putting on a temporary band aid is ok.

Answer (score 4):

While `GetVersionEx` was declared deprecated, if you toss in a proper compatibility manifest declaring compatibility with Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, `GetVersionEx` will return the correct version number.  I use `GetVersionEx` to detect Windows 8 or greater, and because Windows 8 is the last version of Windows to not require a manifest to return the proper Windows version, my code works fine regardless of whether the API returns Windows 6.2, 6.3, 6.4 (for early Windows 10 previews), or 10.0.

With all that said, Microsoft deprecated this API in part due to bad usage of it.  Take for instance this attempt to detect Windows XP or greater:

```
BOOL IsXPOrGreater;
OSVERSIONINFO osver;
osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
GetVersionEx(&osver);
if((osver.dwMajorVersion >= 5) && (osver.dwMinorVersion >=1) IsXPOrGreater = TRUE;
else IsXPOrGreater = FALSE;
```

This sample would return TRUE on Windows XP, Server 2003, 7, 8, and 8.1 but would return FALSE on Windows Vista or 10.  Adding one line would fix this:

```
BOOL IsXPOrGreater;
OSVERSIONINFO osver;
osver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
GetVersionEx(&osver);
if((osver.dwMajorVersion >= 5) && (osver.dwMinorVersion >=1) IsXPOrGreater = TRUE;
else if(osver.dwMajorVersion >= 6) IsXPOrGreater = TRUE;
else IsXPOrGreater = FALSE;
```

This sample would function correctly because it knows that if the major version is 6 or greater than it is greater than XP.

Answer (score 3):

if you look at `sysinfoapi.h`  you will find the following

```
NOT_BUILD_WINDOWS_DEPRECATE
WINBASEAPI
__drv_preferredFunction("IsWindows*", "Deprecated. Use VerifyVersionInfo* or IsWindows* macros from VersionHelpers.")
BOOL
WINAPI
GetVersionExW(
    _Inout_ LPOSVERSIONINFOW lpVersionInformation
    );

#ifdef UNICODE
#define GetVersionEx  GetVersionExW
#else
#define GetVersionEx  GetVersionExA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

if you track the `NOT_BUILD_WINDOWS_DEPRECATE` in the same header file you will find

```
#if defined(FKG_FORCED_USAGE) || defined(WINPHONE) || defined(BUILD_WINDOWS)
# define NOT_BUILD_WINDOWS_DEPRECATE
#else
# define NOT_BUILD_WINDOWS_DEPRECATE __declspec(deprecated)
#endif
```

the above code mean in simple words if you define one of the following
`BUILD_WINDOWS` or `WINPHONE` or `FKG_FORCED_USAGE`  it will not show the deprecated error
so in your code you could do thing like this :

`#define BUILD_WINDOWS`  before `#include <windows.h>`
and that should solve it for you.