# How to get the OS version in Win8.1 as GetVersion/GetVersionEx are deprecated?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, minimumosversion

I have scenarios where i want to specifically know the OS major/minor version and build number etc.

From windows 8.1 onwards `GetVersion` and `GetVersionEx` have been deprecated, stating:

> [[GetVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use the Version Helper functions]

None of the [version helper APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx) help me get the OS version number rather help me verify or get to know if my version is same or above some mentioned version. What can be done?

Comment: I've never yet known Microsoft to remove an API function even when it is deprecated, so I'd say keep using it if you want. Just be aware that in later versions of Windows it lies about the version number unless your manifest specifies compatibility with the current version.

Comment: There is WMI's Win32_OperatingSystem class

Comment: What @Alex says is good. You can always read the version resource from kernel32.

Comment: What is your scenario here exactly? Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22303824/warning-c4996-getversionexw-was-declared-deprecated) stack overflow thread.

Comment: @AlexK. I think you should add it as an answer to this question, because none of the answers were speaking about the WMI query

Answer (score 6):

The API [GetVersionEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) continues to work in Windows 8.1+, but Microsoft has altered its functionality. From MSDN (emphasis mine):

> With the release of Windows 8.1, the behavior of the GetVersionEx API
>   has changed in the value it will return for the operating system
>   version. The value returned by the GetVersionEx function now **depends
>   on how the application is manifested**.
>
> Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 will return the Windows 8
>   OS version value (6.2). Once an application is manifested for a given
>   operating system version, GetVersionEx will always return the version
>   that the application is manifested for in future releases. To manifest
>   your applications for Windows 8.1 please refer to Targeting your
>   application for Windows 8.1.

What you need to do is add the proper GUID(s) to your application (.exe/.dll) binaries (via manifest XML information). In other words, **if you specifically state your application supports 8.1, GetVersionEx() will return proper information** when running on Windows 8.1. If you do not, GetVersionEx() will lie to you.

See [Targeting your application For Windows 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1) for a list of GUIDs. 
Also [covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399302/how-can-i-detect-windows-8-1-in-a-desktop-application) [and here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests).

**GUID List for the Lazy**

- Vista / Server 2008: `{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}`
- Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2: `{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}`
- Windows 8 / Server 2012: `{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}`
- Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 R2 : `{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}`
- Windows 10 / Server 2016: `{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}`

As for Windows Server 2019, I'm not sure that a new GUID has been released. Please comment if you know more!

Comment: What if my application does not have a mainfest?

Comment: You can simply add one in your projects settings. See for example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235229%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that unless you constantly update your application, eventually your manifest will not include the 'latest' version of Windows and you'll get a version lie.

Comment: Also keep in mind that unless you update and test your application on the latest versions it can very likely break. Case in point: GetVersionEx() stops functioning as expected. This is WAD.

Comment: In order to target Windows 8.1, you need to either include the app manifest or include _NT_TARGET_VERSION=$ (_NT_TARGET_VERSION_LATEST) in the source file. Question is where to put include _NT_TARGET_VERSION? which source file?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new function named [GetProductInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx) that returns version infos.

If you want to test for a specific version you should use even [VerifyVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725492(v=vs.85).aspx)

It is easy to create a structure to check whether a specific OS version is running. VerifyVersionInfo takes to version structures and you can easily check for VER_GREATER_EQUAL and VER_LESS_EQUAL

Also note that GetVersionEx doesn't lie on a Windows 8.1 system if you define the correct supported OS entry in the compatibility section for your manifest. But it may lie in a future OS version!

See [Targeting your application For Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx) for a list of GUIDs. Also covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399302/how-can-i-detect-windows-8-1-in-a-desktop-application).

GUID list for the application manifest

- Vista: `{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}`
- Windows 7: `{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}`
- Windows 8: `{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}`
- Windows 8.1: `{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}`
- Windows 10: `{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}`

Comment: I want to get the major, minor and build number of the operating system i am running my program? How can get that using GetProductInfo and VerifyVersionInfo?

Comment: You can get the service pack major number with VerifyVersionInfo. I don't know any situation where a OS build number inside a SP differs...

Comment: `GetProductInfo()` does not return the OS version.  You pass it in a desired OS version, and it returns the *product type* of the OS (business, enterprise, datacenter, etc). This is clearly stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358.aspx): "Retrieves the product type for the operating system on the local computer, and maps the type to the product types supported by the specified operating system."

Answer (score -11):

Check [this article on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73000/Getting-Operating-System-Version-Info-Even-for-Win), It's working perfectly for Windows 8 :

1) Download **.DLL** and add it to your project .

2) Use this code to get **Operation System Information** :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
sb.AppendLine("Operation System Information");
sb.AppendLine("----------------------------");
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Name = {0}", OSVersionInfo.Name));
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Edition = {0}", OSVersionInfo.Edition));
if (OSVersionInfo.ServicePack!=string.Empty)
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Service Pack = {0}", OSVersionInfo.ServicePack));
else
sb.AppendLine("Service Pack = None");
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Version = {0}", OSVersionInfo.VersionString));
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("ProcessorBits = {0}", OSVersionInfo.ProcessorBits));
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("OSBits = {0}", OSVersionInfo.OSBits));
sb.AppendLine(String.Format("ProgramBits = {0}", OSVersionInfo.ProgramBits));

textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```