# Is reading the Windows OS version from the registry safe?

Tags: windows, winapi

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), GetVersionEx (the de facto way of getting the current windows version) has become deprecated as of Windows 8.1. Apparently it returns wrong values (corresponding to Windows 8) if called on a windows 8.1 or 10 machine. However, it can be made to return correctly if the application's manifest is modified correspondingly. But I'm not sure this is such a good solution since

> GetVersionEx may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1

I was thinking of simply reading the information I need from this registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion .

Is there any reason I should avoid doing this, given the current situation (API deprecation) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the OS version in Win8.1 as GetVersion/GetVersionEx are deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246562/how-to-get-the-os-version-in-win8-1-as-getversion-getversionex-are-deprecated)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. In that question a solution for getting the OS is asked. I'm asking whether it's safe or not to get this info from the registry. I see no mention of registry what-so-ever in the other question.

Comment: "*Apparently it returns wrong values (corresponding to Windows 8) if called on a windows 8.1 or 10 machine*" - only if your application does not contain a compatibility manifest for those versions. Read the documentation more carefully.  `GetVersionEx()` is manifest-aware now.  If your app does not explicitly claim to support Windows 8.1 or 10, then `GetVersionEx()` will not report them anymore.  Bu if your app claims to support them, `GetVersionEx()` will report correct information for them as expected.

Comment: I am aware of that. But still, the documentation clearly states that "GetVersionEx may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1". If it won't **exist** anymore at some point, altering the manifest would be pretty much pointless, now wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason I should avoid doing this?

It is plausible that a future version of Windows will not contain the information that you need in that registry key.